# Limit at infinity for $e^{-\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can you, please, confirm my assumption here.  $$\lim_{x\to ∞}e ^ {-\sin{x}}$$ **does not exist**. Due to

- $\lim_{x\to ∞}{\sin{x}}$ doesn't exist
- $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}e^{\ln{f(x)}}=e^L$ if $\lim_{x\to a}{\ln{f(x)} = L}$

Comment: @NasuSama Are you sure that a limit exists?

Comment: @NasuSama: I don't know how you came to that conclusion,but it does not have a limit. It definitely oscillates.

Comment: You can show that it attains the values $e$ and $e^{-1}$ infinitely often..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f=\exp(-\sin)$.

Consider the sequences:

$$
x_n = 2n\pi + \frac \pi 2\\
y_n = 2n\pi - \frac \pi 2
$$

Hence
$$
f(x_n) = \exp(-\sin \pi /2) = 1/e\\
f(y_n) = \exp(-\sin (-\pi /2)) = e\neq 1/e\\
x_n\to\infty\\
y_n\to\infty
$$
Hence there is no limit.

---

In a shorter sequence: using continuity and monotonicity of $\exp$,

$$
\limsup f(x) = f(\limsup (- \sin)) = e> 1/e =
 f(\liminf (- \sin)) = \liminf f(x).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We know $-1 \leq |\sin(x)| \leq 1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{e} \leq \frac{1}{e^{\ sin(x)}} \leq e$.

Comment: what do you thing of: "$-1\le 0\le 1$... this function oscillates, thus having no limit." proving that $\exp 0$ has no limit?

Comment: @Hey123 Just because something is bounded doesn't mean the function oscillates. Also, just because something oscillates, doesn't mean it has no limit. For example $\sin(1/x)$ is bounded, oscillates, and has a limit as $x$ approaches infinity.

Comment: I understand that, but for the purpose of this question, it was enough with composition of the exponential function with a oscillating function.

Comment: Okay. I must be misinterpreting your answer then. The way I read your answer is 'this thing is bounded, hence it oscillates and has no limit'.

Comment: @Hey123: your answer only states that the function is bounded, nothing else.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, but yes I was using the fact that $e^x$ is entire and $\sin(x)$ oscillates and bounded $\rightarrow$ the function the OP posted will be bounded and oscillating.